# Explanation of columns in reputation league

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I think it could be useful to explain somewhere on [reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/) pages what the columns actually mean.

I balked a little when at first I saw "changes" of ±50k, thinking that to be the amount of reputation change the user had earned in a week - but then I figured it must be the amount their overall position in the user heirarchy has moved?

The "rank" appears to be based on the rightmost column, but other than that I'm at a loss to explain how any of the columns reconcile to events.  Grateful for an explanation!

Comment: Would "rank change" be less confusing than "change"?

Comment: @Emmett: Yes, I think so (although it might still not be *entirely* clear that this is movement in one's rank in the reputation league table, rather than movement in one's rank amongst all users).  It might also be worth having a comment somewhere on the page that the tables are only refreshed once/day or whatever?

Comment: @emmettl: "I've submitted a feature request to add column headers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The columns seem pretty straightforward, except possibly "change".

- Week/month/quarter/year rank is the ranking of users in that range, so [week rank](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) sorts people by the amount of rep they've earned that week; the person at #1 has earned the most rep this week of anyone on the site
- Change is how much they moved from the previous week/month/quarter/year. For example, [this week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2012-04-22) has [Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286723/agarwal) at #1, and his change is +57, so [last week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2012-04-15?sort=reputationchange&page=2) he was #58th (he moved up 57 places, from #58 to #1)
- Total reputation is the user's...total reputation
- Week/month/quarter/year reputation is how much reputation the user earned in that amount of time. Since this is what controls their rank, if you have the page sorted by rank this will be monotonically decreasing as you go down the list

Comment: But, in my case at least, total reputation is showing a number that is different to my total reputation.  Likewise, week reputation is showing a number that is less than my reputation earned over the past week.

Comment: @eggyal On your profile page your total rep is 680 and you've earned 190 for the day so far. The league says your total rep is 490. (680-190=490). This suggests that this data is cached. Except for some strange reason if you look at the [alltime rep](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) which seems to be kept up-to-date

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: Aha, hadn't considered that.  Thanks.