# Reputation league: total vs week reputation

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What does this reputation mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164602/what-does-this-reputation-mean)

I have some time to lose at work and I was looking at the [reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2013-01-20?sort=reputationchange). How is it possible that the current leader has a total reputation which is less than the week reputation?
I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130117/explanation-of-columns-in-reputation-league) which seems in some way related to my curiosity (read the comments to the answer, where the OP writes `But, in my case at least, total reputation is showing a number that is different to my total reputation`), but I think it is not my case since if you look at the leader profile the total reputation shown is the same as shown in the league. Moreover, from his profile, week reputation seems to be `10`, not more than `2k`. Have I misunderstood the reputation league calculation?

Comment: Because he gave a highly upvoted answer to a popular question which was later removed.

Comment: @Bart, thanks! and BTW, this is an exact duplication (I am referring to the same case), I just didn't find the previous question!

Comment: Why was his answer removed instead of [the whole question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently/14419496#14419496) ? Is this discussed somewhere ?

Comment: @dystroy Partially here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164570/why-was-my-answer-deleted-without-any-appropriate-reason and here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164379/is-a-question-asking-for-an-algorithm-to-sort-socks-into-pairs-on-topic

Comment: @dystroy Here also. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164379/is-a-question-asking-for-an-algorithm-to-sort-socks-into-pairs-on-topic

Comment: Man he is more popular after deleting his answer than before.. I count this as the 4th similar question..